# Multiple inheritance same method name and no ambiguity

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have two classes (A0 and A1) that have a function foo() and a A0 has a function bar() that just calls foo(). And a class B that inherits from A0 and A1.

B does nothing beside inheriting from A0 and A1.

Why is there no ambiguity when calling `B->bar()` ?

A small code sample

```
class A0
{
protected:
    /*virtual*/ void foo() {std::cout << "A0" << std::endl; }
public:
    void bar() {foo(); }
};

class A1
{
protected:
    /*virtual*/ void foo() {std::cout << "A1" << std::endl; }
};

class B : public A0, public A1
{
protected:
    //virtual void foo() override {A1::foo(); }
};

int main()
{
    B *lPtr = new B;
    lPtr->bar(); //"A0" without the override, "A1" with the override
    delete lPtr;

    return 0;
}
```

And if I uncomment the virtual and the function override, there is still no ambiguity but it calls the other foo.

Why is there still no ambiguity and why does it call the other one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case you have `virtual` there are two `foo`s in your vtable.

The first one is `A0::foo` the second one is `A1::foo`.

When you override `foo` in `B`, you override *both*, and instruct it to call `A1::foo()`.

If you don't override `foo` in `B`, the two `foo`s remain in the vtable, unrelated except by name.

In `A0::bar`, when you call `foo()` it looks locally for a `foo`.  It sees one -- `A0::foo` -- which is virtual.  So it encodes a call into the vtable to execute `A0::foo`.

Without the override in `B` the invokes `A0::foo`.  With the override in `B` this invokes `B::foo` when then calls `A1::foo` instead.

In the case you don't have `virtual`, well, the same holds except the `vtable` bit.

You have two functions `A0::foo` and `A1::foo`.  With a pointer to `A0`, `->foo()` invokes `A0::foo`.

With a pointer to `B`, `->foo()` is ambiguous.

If you write a `B::foo` method (does not matter if it is virtual), then `B->foo()` invokes it.

---

The fact that two things share a name doesn't mean they are the same thing, nor does it make all calls ambiguous.

The calls are ambiguous only if you cannot tell which one is being named from context.